# FancyBox - Jquery Errors

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox

I am using Fancybox.  The Fancybox's sample works fine, but when I bring it into my own folder, I get an issue.

If I write:

```
$(document).ready(

    function() {

        $('.gallery a').fancybox(
            {
                overlayColor : '#060',
                overlayOpacity : .3

            }
        );

});
```

The Console errors shows:

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined 
$(document).ready(
```

The page didn't work out!

I hit F12 and check all the  JS and CSS files' connections, they are connected, but I still get an error.  Any idea, please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery - $ is not defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined)

Comment: I had `js/jquery-1.9.1.js` linked into the file

Comment: Make sure that jQuery is being loaded before everything else :-)

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of network tab after hitting F12 (Web Developer tools)

Comment: This is the Errors screen shot after I try to delete all unrelated codes and leave only Fancybox code and the links to JS and CSS files `http://oi62.tinypic.com/312v890.jpg`

Comment: can I see network tab screenshot?

Comment: I upgrated fancyBox and it works.  Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Include jquery.js at top of all javascript file

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

or if you have already added it than check your file path

Comment: I just added your link, but it doesn't work, either.  I try to delete all unrelated codes and leave only Fancybox code and the links to JS and CSS files, it doesn't work, either.